# How to convert a FITS file to .xls Excel file?

Tags: soft-question, software

We are trying to determine the isophots in elliptical galaxies in order
to check De-Vaucouleurs law. To do so, we want to convert the data from a
FITS file to Excel and analyze it using Excel math capabilities. Does
someone know how to make such a conversion?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, NASA's FTools software contains a program that will do this for you.  Go to the [FTools website](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/ftools/ftools_menu.html) and download a copy of the HEATOOLS.  You want to specify that you want the Fimage package on the download page.  Since you're running windows, you'll proabably need to download the PC-Cygwin package and install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) as well as there is no native Windows versions.  Alternately you can try the FTools through NASA's online interface called [WebHera](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/webHera/).

In either case the tool you want to use is called **fimgdump** this will dump an image into an ASCII text file that you can then import into Excel.

Of course if you want a whole suite of image analysis software, I strongly recommend looking at [IRAF](http://www.iraf.net).  It is a old, but well tested and still widely used astronomical software data analysis package.

Comment: Good answer, and I'll repeat your IRAF suggestion - it's going to be much better for most analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a few files to convert, and you don't want to install software yourself, the CDF group at GSFC offers a web service that will convert from FITS to ASCII, which can then be imported in Excel:

- http://translators.gsfc.nasa.gov/

If you have more to convert, and you're willing to do a little programming, there's a WSDL description to generate a SOAP client.  They also have already compiled applications to do some of the conversions, but you'd have to take the `FITS -> CDF -> ASCII` route to use those:

- http://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/html/dtws3.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I'll be checking those two. I was combing the web and found few additional sights. The next one offers a list of "FITS I/O Libraries":
http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html#java_grosbol
I already tried opening a FITS file with MATLAB. It created a new int16 array which I used to create 3D meshes of NGC5921. You can view them here:
https://picasaweb.google.com/108572494054451266909/NGC5921#

Comment: Alon, did you know you can edit your original question body? This allows you to keep it up to date with any progressions / further information you might come across; this post is an excellent candidate for a question update and it would be great if you would take the time to edit it in.